# How to pass certain typedef of a class to template

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

In the following task I want to create a template which only accepts typedefs defined in the following class CDataFormat:

```
class CDataFormat{
public:
    typedef unsigned short  element_t;
    typedef unsigned int accumulation_t;
    typedef double division_t;
};
```

Now the following implemention works fine.

```
template<typename DF, int SIZE>
class CFilter{
private:
    DF m_memberName[SIZE];
public: 
    void whatever(){
    //CFilter<CDataFormat::division_t, 8> smth; // Just a small test
    }
};
```

However it's not ensured that the template only accepts a member of CDataFormat.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper class and `static_assert` to meet your needs.

```
#include <type_traits>

class CDataFormat{
public:
    typedef unsigned short  element_t;
    typedef unsigned int accumulation_t;
    typedef double division_t;

}; 

template <typename T> struct is_valid_type
{
   static const bool value = std::is_same<T, CDataFormat::element_t>::value ||
                             std::is_same<T, CDataFormat::accumulation_t>::value ||
                             std::is_same<T, CDataFormat::division_t>::value ;
};

template<typename DF, int SIZE>
class CFilter{
  static_assert(is_valid_type<DF>::value, "Unsupported type");
  private:
    DF m_memberName[SIZE];
  public: 
    void whatever(){
    }
};
```

With that,

```
CFilter<CDataFormat::element_t, 10> f1;
```

will work without any problem but use of

```
CFilter<int, 20> f2;
```

will result in a compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `static_assert` to report misusage:

```
template <typename DF, int SIZE>
class CFilter{
static_assert(std::is_same<CDataFormat::element_t, DF>::value
           || std::is_same<CDataFormat::accumulation_t, DF>::value
           || std::is_same<CDataFormat::division_t, DF>::value, "Unexpected type");

private:
    DF m_memberName[SIZE];
};
```